# How to launch landscape view from portrait in iphone?

Tags: iphone

Im new to iPhone developer, I have a Login screen in Iphone, when i run, it displayed in half screen only, then i change the orientation it displayed the login screen in landscape mode, but i want when i launched the app it displayed in landscape mode in portrait and navigation to another screen also landscape mode in portrait, how? please any one help me

```
 - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:()
 {
UIDeviceOrientation orientation = [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation];
if (orientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft ||
         orientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight )
{
    return YES;
}  
else if (orientation == UIDeviceOrientationPortrait ||orientation ==    UIDeviceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)
{ 
    return NO;
}
 }
```

Used these code not working in landscape mode in portrait, but i change the orientation it will worked.

Comment: Hi, My problem is how to launch landscape view in portrait? thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation];

    [self willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:orientation duration:0];


}

-(void) willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
    if(toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown )
    {
    set the view for potrait
    }
    else if(toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight )
    {
    set the view for landscape
    }


}
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    // Overriden to allow any orientation.
    return YES;
}
```

Hope this help u.

Answer (score 0):

what does it mean: "landscape in portrait" ??? you have this or that, cannot have both at the same time (unless you have to iPhones ;P )

in plist file you can determin which mode will be launched on startup of app :) "Initial interface orientation" with values for each of four orientations. fastest way to set this thing. though to manage later on in app when to rotate or not, you should use

`-(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:`

hope this helps :)